# Can this pandas code be simplified?

Tags: python, pandas, simplify

I wrote this piece of code which does exactly what I need it to do. I was wondering if there is a way of simplifying this because it seems a little redundant. The only reason I feel like it might not be is because of the second step (which creates a new column).

```
sorted_vals = df[df['binary'] == '0'].sort_values(by='height')
sorted_vals['rank'] = sorted_vals['height'].rank(ascending=1)
sorted_vals = sorted_vals.groupby(['school']).mean()
```

Edit: As per suggestion, here is a sample data set I would be working with (from a csv file):

```
id,name,binary,state,height
1,"Bob",0,NY,74.93
2,"Matt",1,NJ,67.1
3,"Chad",0,TN,65.93
4,"Maria",0,NJ,73.48
5,"Riley",1,NY,70.67
```

I would first want to separate the data by the "binary" attribute, as I need to calculate the rankings in terms of height separately for the two groups. After I separate the two, I want to create a new column ranking them by height. My ultimate goal is to rank the states by which has the tallest people, so I then recombine the two rankings I just found and find the mean height by state.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In any case, take a look at [`DataFrame.assign()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), which could (arguably) make your code simpler.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't know. How do I move it there?

Comment: @mildlyillogical, alternatively you can add small sample data set, short description of what you are trying to achieve and expected / desired data set - this would help us to understand your goal(s) and to test our solutions

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a help column, for example in R doing so can lead in significant speed improvements when used right... Now with a quick look of your code, I take it you are interested in computing the mean rank? In this case that should be fine... Of course if you wanted absolute rank couldn't you compute the mean height and then sort/rank the groupby school output?